# If $\{f_n\}\subset A(\mathbb{\Omega})$ is normal then for $\{m_n\}$, $m_n\rightarrow\infty$, a subsequence $\{f_n^{m_n}\}$ is normal.

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

**Question**: Is it true that if $\{f_n\}\subset A(\mathbb{\Omega})$ is normal then for some sequence $\{m_n\}$, $m_n\rightarrow\infty$, a subsequence $\{f_n^{m_n}\}$ is normal.

**My Thoughts**: Since $\{f_n\}$ is normal, then there is some subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ which converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{\Omega}$.  So, if I take $m_n=\frac{1}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}$, would this work?  This feels like I am trying to prove the "other" definition of normal by saying the aforementioned subsequences must converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{\Omega}$, OR tend to $\infty$ uniformly... but I suppose that just because $m_n\rightarrow\infty$, does not necessarily imply that $\{f_n^{m_n}\}\rightarrow\infty$.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: What is $A(\mathbb D)$? Analytic functions on $\mathbb D$? Automorphisms of $\mathbb D$?

Comment: There must be something missing. $f_n(z) = 2$ a bounded (and therefore normal) family of holomorphic functions in $\Bbb D$. But $f_n^{m_n}(z) = 2^{m_n} \to \infty$ for any subsequence.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, my (quite stupid) mistake.  We are working with an arbitrary domain $\Omega$ here, not $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Well, if the theorem holds for an arbitrary domain then it must hold in particular for $\Omega = \Bbb D$. Are you sure that the problem is stated correctly?

Comment: @MartinR I am (once again) an idiot.  This problem is from an old qualifier list, and it starts with "is it true that".... I suppose that is quite the difference :)  I'll edit the question, but then your first comment is a perfect answer.

Comment: @MartinR I have a quick question... wen you say that $f_n(z)=2$ is a bounded family of analytic function in $\mathbb{D}$, to be in $\mathbb{D}$, wouldn't we need $|f_n(z)|\leq 1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @User7238: $f_n(z)$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb D$, one its *values* are outside of $\Bbb D$. So it depends on what exactly is meant with $A(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\{z\}$ as the normal family on $\mathbb{C}$

Then for any $m_n\to \infty$, the family
$\{z^{m_n}\}$ is easily seen not to be normal.